# Deal with an Excel table with Python

Tags: python, excel

**I would like to deal with an Excel table with Python, but have a problem.**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import xlrd
from xlwt import *

book = xlrd.open_workbook('myExcel.xls')  #open a table
sheet = book.sheets()[0]
nrows = sheet.nrows
books = []
for i in range(nrows):
    value = sheet.cell_value(i, 5)
    if value == u'李雷':
        ss = sheet.row_values(i)
        for ii in range(len(ss)):
            data = ss[ii]  #get data in the specified row
            books.append(data)

newbook = Workbook(encoding = 'utf-8')  # open a new table
newsheet = newbook.add_sheet('李雷')
for item in books:
    for item_row in range(2, 100):
        for item_col in range(7):
            newsheet.write(item_row, item_col, label = item)  #write data
newbook.save('newExcel.xls')
```

- 日期   单号  项目  金额  结算  业务员
- 12.1 100001  A   100 现金  李雷
- 12.1 100002  D   200 现金  韩梅梅
- 12.1 100003  A   100 现金  李雷
- 12.1 100004  E   450 现金  小明
- 12.1 100005  R   430 现金  小明
- 12.1 100006  A   100 现金  李雷
- 12.1 100007  A   100 现金  李雷
- 12.1 100008  A   100 现金  李雷
- 12.1 100010  A   90  现金  韩梅梅
- 12.1 100011  K   120 现金  小红

**It cann't work.what's wrong?**

*Exception: Attempt to overwrite cell: sheetname=u'\u674e\u96f7' rowx=2 colx=0*

Answer (score 2):

You need to allow overwrites:

```
newsheet = newbook.add_sheet('李雷',cell_overwrite_ok=True)
```

Comment: Otherwise, only a single write per cell is allowed.

Comment: Thanks.Something wrong.I want all about "李雷" of data, not all cells are ' 李雷'.

Comment: @Koo,sorry I don't quite understand your comment, the error is specifically about `"李雷"`, are you getting other errors?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks for your reply. Run the script after I modified, and all cells are ' 李雷'. I don't know why? This is not what I want. In the upper part, 'data' is clearly the row data of '李雷', write to Excel it turned '李雷'